# Laview PID.vi continues when event case is False

Tags: labview, motordriver, pid-controller

I'm looking for a way to disable the PID.vi from running in Labview when the event case container is **false**. 
The program controls motor position to maintain constant tension on a cable using *target force* and *actual force* as the input parameters. The output is *motor position*. Note that reinitialize is set to **false** since it needs previous instances to spool the motor.

[image: Diagram]

Currently, when the event case is **true** the motor spools as expected and maintains the cable tension. But when the event case state is toggled the PID.vi seems to be running in the background when **false** causing the motor spool sporatically.

Is there a way to freeze the PID controls so that it continues from where it left off?

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

The PID VI does not run in the background. It only executes when you call it. That said, PID is a time-based calculation. It calculates the difference from the last time you called the VI and uses that to calculate the new values. If a lot of time passed, it will just try to fix it using that data.

If you want to freeze the value and then resume fixing smoothly, you can use the limits input on the top and set the max and min to your desired output. This will cause the PID VI to always output that value. You will probably need a feedback node or shift register to remember the last value output by the PID.

Answer (score 1):

What Yair said is not entirely true - the integral and derivative terms are indeed time dependent, but the proportional is not.  A great reference for understanding PIDs and how they are implemented in LabVIEW can be found [here](http://www.ni.com/pdf/manuals/372192d.pdf) (not sure why it is archived).  Also, the PID VIs are coded in G so you can simply open them to see how they operate.

If you take a closer look at the PID VI, you can see what is happening and why you might not get the response you expect. In the VI itself, `dt` will be either 1) what you set it to, or 2) an accumulation of time based on a tick count stored in the VI (the default).  Since you have not specified a `dt`, the PID algorithm uses the accumulated time between calls.  If you have "paused" calculation for some time, this will have an impact on the integral and derivative output.

The derivative output will kick in when there is a change in the *process variable* (use of the process variable prevents derivative kick).  The effect of a large accumulated time between calls will be to reduce the response of this term.  The time that you have paused will have a more significant impact on the integral term.  Since the response of the integral portion of the controller is the proportional to the integral of the error over `dt`, the longer you pause the larger the response simply because because the the algorithm is performing a trapezoidal integration over `dt`.

My first suggestion is *don't pause the controller* - let the PID do what it is supposed to do.  If you are using it properly, then you should not have to stop the controller action.  But, if you must pause the controller action, consider re-initializing the controller.  This will force the controller to reset the accumulated time term and the response in the first iteration will be purely proportional.

Hope this helps.

Comment: mtat76 you answered my question. 

*If you have "paused" calculation for some time, this will have an impact on the integral and derivative output.*

Thank you very much. I will avoid pausing and reinitialize instead.